# Get Filtered numeric data from alphanumeric field in binding Source control in winform application

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Binding Source control, which is binded to a table named Customer. There is a column named "CustomerNo", in this table which contains alphanumeric data. I want to apply a filter on Binding Source that it only shows rows which has only numeric values in "CustomerNo" and value must be in range 13 to 20.

for example if i have following data in CustomerNo column.

```
10
11
12
13
14
as55
as66
as77
15
```

so it should give me the following result.(As my filter range is 13-20 and i need only numerice values)

```
14
15
```

Mean while i just want to apply filter on numeric values of alphanumeric column.

Kindly help me resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CustomerNo from (
    select CustomerNo   from customers
where ISNUMERIC(CustomerNo )=1 ) c
where c.CustomerNo between 13 and 20
```

Use this query or create a view and use it

Comment: I hope it helps you or others